# How to number half of a booklet with Roman numerals, and the other half with normal numbers in Word?

Tags: book, document-setup, numbering

I am having difficulties making the first part of a booklet to have Roman numerals and the second part to have normal numbering.

i.e. summary, table of contents etc to have `i`, `ii`, `iii` as the numbers and from introduction to 1, 2, 3 etc.

I am using word for the booklet which I intend to convert to PDF.

**How can I set different numbering systems on different parts of my Word document?**

Comment: Isn't this off-topic for this SE? Shouldn't this be in Writing SE?

Comment: This is off-topic for this site, but if i remember correctly, what you need to do it to create different _sections_. Google will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

you should make **section break** giving the first section a roman numbering while the second section having a regular numerical numbering.